# I'm in danger of being blocked from asking questions, but I have asked no question?

Tags: support, feature-request, status-declined

Why have I received this warning if apparently I haven't asked any questions?

[image: Don't get it]

If I *have* asked a question and it was deleted, why can't I see it privately? This would be useful so that I can remember what the problems were with the questions I had asked, and avoid the same mistake.

Note that I've asked a question after posting this issue here on meta, so now I do have one question asked. But the point is, by telling me my questions from long ago weren't well received but not linking to them, I can't easily refer back to those questions and avoid doing again whatever caused them to be deleted.

Comment: I can see you have posted 3 question [1](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/36830/why-were-the-med-beds-restricted-to-elysium), [2](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/32117/limitless-lucy-and-similar-movies-that-could-prime-you-to-be-smarter), [3](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10208/where-could-i-find-the-cruise-ship-2002-documentary-on-the-island-escape-ship). 2nd and 3rd was completely off topic , so that might be reason for the warning message. Don't worry you are not blocked yet and not going to be if you don't post off-topic repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks @Ankit. May I suggest keeping my question #2 closed, but undeleted, so that others can find it?  Here's the [justification on Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-good-duplicates/32315#32315). Basically, we want duplicates to remain visible so that future searches for those terms reach the original question, and also prevent new duplicates from being created.

Comment: That will be injustice to already deleted 100s of suggestion question and that will set a bad example, we already have a generic suggestion question for it.

Comment: @AnkitSharma: the suggestion engine finds question with common words, not common meanings. That's why it didn't find the duplicate when I asked my question #2. As to your other objection, perhaps those 100s duplicate questions shouldn't have been deleted in the first place, but left closed. Can I get someone else's opinion on this, or are you the only moderator? I have provided the guidelines from Meta.SE, and Jeff Atwood's intent as well, and I believe Movies.SE should follow the same principle: duplicate questions are closed, *bad* questions are deleted.

Comment: Yes you can wait for other mods reply too.....even meta is a place where any user can give there input.

Comment: As said, the problem with that deleted question is, that it *is* a bad question. It is not so much a proper question that just happened to have been asked before (which I agree should not be deleted), but a recommendation question, which are completely off-topic. In fact it should rather have been closed as off-topic (and closed questions with negative score *are* deleted because they're bad) and not as a duplicate, as adressed in [this related discussion](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1846/49). (Note also that not all of those "100 suggestion questions" were closed as duplicates.)

Comment: That being said, the valid issue you adress in your question might be more properly handled on [meta.se], since it is a problem with the entire SE framework that is not so much specific to this site (and which we can't really do anything against here).

Comment: Agreed, #2 is not a duplicate question - its off topic.

Comment: I'm marking this `status-declined` for now, since we're bound to the network-wide SE functionality for this and the post on the main meta is tagged this way, too, even if the functionality is actually *partially* existing, as explained in the answers.

Answer (score 2):

There have previously been [long-standing requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/162011) about showing all your deleted questions and answers on your profile (since you can view them anyway if you had a link to them) on the [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), discussed with their pros and cons, which is currently [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), though. So the best way to support those efforts would be to engage into furthering those requests there, as that is actually an issue to be tackled on a network wide basis.

However, that linked request also provides part of a solution to the problem: If the question or answer was deleted during the last 60 days, you can already view them on your profile. There is a little link at the bottom of the [questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/4206/dan-dascalescu?tab=questions)/[answers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/4206/dan-dascalescu?tab=answers) page, which says *"deleted recent questions/answers"*:

[image]

But if the deletion is really older than 60 days, you will only to be able to see the question if you have a link to it, which might not be easy to get. But if you have at least 10k reputation (which also enables you to view all deleted posts in general), you can search for your own deleted posts by including a `deleted:yes` in any [search queries](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search), as explained in [this related meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145060/162011) and its answers.

Comment: It would take me years to get 10k reputation. That's basically denying access to my own content.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Well, complain to SE, it's the answer nevertheless. You might also want to consider that the conent isn't really so much your own at all anymore since you posted it. That's also why you aren't generally allowed to delete your own questions and answers either when they're well-received by the community.